# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\mu(k)}{k}}$, where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, analytic-number-theory, mobius-function

After I've read [1], I am curious about next question.

> **Question.** Let for integers $n\geq 1$ the Möbius function $\mu(n)$. Is it possible to prove when for complex numbers $z\neq 0$ 
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\mu(k)}{k}}\tag{1}$$ is convergent? Provide me hints or details. **Many thanks.**

I hope, after I was inspired in [1], that previous exercise has mathematical meaning. Feel free if you need to define a branch of the complex logarithmic, to do it.

You've the definiton of the Möbius function, for example from this [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MoebiusFunction.html). I believe that I need an explicit estimation for the Möbius function.

### References:

[1] *Problem No. 5*, Problem of the Week (Spring 2007 Series), from the Department of Mathematics of Purdue University.

Comment: No comment. ${}{}{}$

Comment: I'm sorry my problem is that was tired, I thought that my question was a good question (inspired in a good question) @reuns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit of the exponent as n goes to infinity is the reciprocal of the zeta function evaluated at 1. Since Zeta of 1 is the harmonic series, the reciprocal is 0. So the terms approach 1, and the series is divergent.

Proof of Zeta Reciprocal:

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Reciprocal_of_Riemann_Zeta_Function

Comment: Many thanks for your contribution.

Comment: Extremely late comment, but the fact that the series $\sum_n \frac{\mu(n)}{n}$ converges to zero is a highly non-trivial fact, which turns out to be equivalent to the prime number theorem.